# How to run code with Hydrogen

Tags: python, atom-editor, jupyter, hydrogen

I am completely new to Atom.

I installed it and it felt quite easy to use and set up. I read that the Hydrogen package enables functionality similar to the Jupyter Notebook. So I installed the package.
Unfortunately, I have no Idea how to use it. I read the entire documentation (which isnt too extensive) and searched for everything I could.

So here is my problem:
I created a file called testfile1.py
In that file i put the very simple line

```
print(‘Hello’)
```

just to see how it works. I marked the line and pressed Ctrl+Enter. At the top right, a window pops up saying “Hydrogen Kernels updated: Python 3”.
But then nothing happens. I dont see the result of the code that I tried to run anywhere. I tried different lines of codes, tried differen run-combinations, nothing gives me any results.
I am using arch linux, installed Anaconda through the AUR to /opt/anaconda.
Using the terminal and running

```
jupyter notebook
```

for example works just fine and opens a Notebook in Firefox (as it should) and running code that imports modules that came along with Anaconda also work fine once i run them with the script package in Atom
(things like

```
import numpy as np
```

is letting me work with all the numpy funtions as expected. So I think that it shouldnt be any issues related to the Anaconda packages itself)
I tried to look everywhere I could, but I do not find any solution on why hydrogen would not give me any results.
Is there anything I am missing or did wrong?
I hope someone might be able to help me, thanks already in advance

Answer (score 3):

I'm using Windows 10,  Atom version 1.30.0 with Hydrogen 2.6.0 (both with default settings).

If you navigate to Packages > Hydrogen you can see the default key bindings.

[image: Packages > Hydrogen]

To make a cell there are many options noted in the [manual](https://nteract.gitbooks.io/hydrogen/content/docs/Usage/GettingStarted.html#hydrogen-run-cell) as shown below.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I found I had to re-start Atom after updating the python kernel. Then the run code commands worked as expected.

Answer (score -1):

You need to select all the lines which you want to execute with the cursor and then press ctrl+enter (or shift+enter depending on your keybinding).

**There are two ways to tell Hydrogen which code in your file to run.**

***Selected code:*** 
If you have code selected when you hit Run, Hydrogen will run exactly that code.

***Current block:*** 
With no code selected, Hydrogen will try to find the complete block that's on or before the current line.

- If the line you're on is already a complete expression (like s = "abracadabra"), Hydrogen will run just that line.
- If the line you're on is the start of a block like a for loop, Hydrogen will run the whole block.
- If the line you're on is blank, Hydrogen will run the first block above that line.